# Icon not showing in button story

Tags: vuejs3, storybook

I need some help. I succesfully installed and run Storybook ("@storybook/vue3": "^6.5.15").
I am now working on the first component, our buttons.

Our buttons all have icons, so I need a way to include our icon package inside the Storybook stories. Ofcourse it would be great to include them globally, but at this point, I don't mind including them manually into each story that needs it.

The icon package is BootstrapIcon ("@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons": "^1.0.5").

In the app, I include it in the main.js file, like this (and this works for the whole app):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import i18n from './i18n'
import "bootstrap"
import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';
import "@/assets/scss/styles.scss";

const app = createApp(App)

i18n.setup()
app.use(i18n.vueI18n)
app.use(router)
app.component('BootstrapIcon', BootstrapIcon);

app.mount('#app')
```

So now I try to make the icon work in the Button story, but it doesnt show up in the dark blue area (see screenshot below) and I don't know why.

I tried importing it in the .storybook/preview.js but no luck. I tried importing it in the Button.vue file and in the Button.stories.js. There is no error message in the console, it's just blank:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is the stories/Button.vue code:

```
<template>
  <a @click="onClick" class="btn-icon-split" :class="classes">
        <span class="icon">
            <BootstrapIcon icon="telephone-fill" />
        </span>
        <span class="text">{{ content }}</span>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
import './button.scss';
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';
import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';

export default {
  name: 'button',
  components: 'BootstrapIcon',
  props: {
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    primary: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      validator: function (value) {
        return ['sm', 'lg'].indexOf(value) !== -1;
      },
    },
    class: {
      type: String,
    },
    circle: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },

  emits: ['click'],

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    props = reactive(props);
    return {
      classes: computed(() => ({
        'storybook-button': true,
        'btn btn-primary': props.primary,
        'btn btn-secondary': !props.primary,
        [`btn-${props.size || ''}`]: true,
      })),
      onClick() {
        emit('click');
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

And this is my Button.stories.js file:

```
import Button from './Button.vue';
import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';

// More on default export: https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-stories/introduction#default-export
export default {
  title: 'Components/Button',
  component: Button,
  // More on argTypes: https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/api/argtypes
  argTypes: {
    onClick: {},
    size: {
      control: { type: 'select' },
      options: ['small', 'large'],
    },
    circle: false,
    classes: 'btn btn-icon-split'
  },
};

// More on component templates: https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-stories/introduction#using-args
const Template = (args) => ({
  // Components used in your story `template` are defined in the `components` object
  components: { Button },
  // The story's `args` need to be mapped into the template through the `setup()` method
  setup() {
    return { args };
  },
  // And then the `args` are bound to your component with `v-bind="args"`
  template: `<Button v-bind="args" />`
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
// More on args: https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-stories/args
Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  content: 'Button',
  icon: 'send-fill',
  class: 'btn btn-icon-split btn-primary',
  circle: false
};

export const Secondary = Template.bind({});
Secondary.args = {
  content: 'Button',
  icon: 'send-fill'
};

export const Large = Template.bind({});
Large.args = {
  size: 'lg',
  content: 'Button',
  icon: 'send-fill'
};

export const Small = Template.bind({});
Small.args = {
  size: 'sm',
  content: 'Button',
  icon: 'send-fill'
};
```

Extra info: My project runs without Webpack & I prefer to keep it that way, as it is build with Vite and Im not familiair enough with both to make them work together. There is also a Vite config file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using this in preview.js:

> ```
> import {app} from '@storybook/vue3';
> import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';
> app.component('BootstrapIcon', BootstrapIcon);
> ```

---

**UPDATE 2024**

app is no longer exported so above code won't work in new installs, you need to import them for each story like this:

Button.vue:

```
<script>
import './button.scss';
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';
import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';


export default {
  name: 'Button',
  components: {BootstrapIcon},
  props: {
```